# Installing Epson XP-424 wireless printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I tried to install an Epson XP-424 wireless printer on my Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Originally, I attempted to add it directly from "Printers" in "System Settings". This specific model is not listed, so I tried the generic 9-pin driver and then the generic 24-pin driver. I got the same result either way, which is that, it appears installed, but when I send a job to the printer, it spits out nothing but blank paper.

I was able to install the Epson app on my iPhone, and I can print from my phone, so I know there is no problem with the hardware, the ink levels, etc.

I am sort of stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific driver for your printer.  They are available on the [Epson website](https://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=266642&infoType=Downloads&platform=OSF_O_LINUX)  To use them you will need to install a specific package as mentioned in the Epson downloads:

`sudo apt-get install lsb`

The specific package that you need to download depends on your version of Ubuntu. If you are running a 32 bit Ubuntu, download `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb`

And if you are running 64 bit Ubuntu, download `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

These files can be opened using the Ubuntu Software Center by double-clicking on them, or installed from the command line by the command

`sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Thanks, Charles, that was quite helpful, and it seems to have done the trick. 

I never would have found the driver without these instructions.  I based my download off of your suggested file name:
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb 

Anyway, to summarize for any other dummies like me, you have to:

1) Install lsb
2) Find the driver on the Epson website (this was the hardest part) and download it
3) Install the driver either from the Software Center or command line
4) Add the printer from "Printers" in "System Settings".

Next, how to install the scanner?

Comment: It was the "Download Printer Driver  ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)" page on the Epson website (which is somewhat disorganized).

Comment: Direct link: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=52091&DSCCHK=bb4e5eb8325d18119ac78e87c10a5b14c4213ae4